# trying to prove that HALT is RE-HARD

Tags: computability

I'm trying to show  that for every $L \in RE $ , there is    $L\leq_m HALT$.

can you tell if my reduction is true?

The reduction, while  getting input $x\in L$,

builds a T.M machine D, that upon some input   $x_1$, D is running M on $x$,
if M halted on x, D accepts and the reduction  returns $<M,x>$.

otherwise, D is doing what M does: loop.

does it a correct reduction? thanks.

Comment: We don't usually check proofs. Do you have any particular doubt? Otherwise, please ask your TA (if you have one) for help.

Comment: We don't? Why is that? I can see that we'd have to get our hands dirty with really messed up proofs, or at least with poorly stated one (like the above), but so what?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @AndrejBauer. I agree, but that puts the two of us in the minority. This question has been hashed over in meta, with generally the same result, "that's not the way we work here, since [insert unconvincing argument here]." I just live with it.

Comment: ok, i will reframe it. can the reduction  say; "if M halted on x" then...." ?

Comment: @D.W.: Proofs are hardly ever answered by "yes/no", they will mostly get answers of the sort "here is how you can improve your proof" and that *is* useful to future visitors. Is there a programming SE site which prohibits questions of the form "is this code ok"? That is analogous to this situation.